# Can you forward-reference a named capture group in JS regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

So the thing I'm trying to do with regex (JS flavor) is essentially to match words with double letters (i.e. two instances of the same character, directly adjacent to each other), but only capture the second letter. So for example, I would want to capture the second `t` in `letter`, the second `n` in `manner`, and the second `s` in `glass`.

The way I thought to go about this with a backreference to a named capture group, which I called `ditto`. So in this case the regex would be `/(?:\k<ditto>)(?<ditto>t|n|s)/g`...

...*but* this ended up matching strings it shouldn't have, namely strings with only a single `t`, `n` or `s` - i.e., it's matching the exact the same thing as `/[tns]/g` - and I just figured out it's because `\k` can't backreference a `<ditto>` match that hasn't been found yet, so the first capture group might as well just be empty.

So what I actually need is a forward-reference, not a backreference, but those... don't exist, do they? Then how else would you accomplish the same thing?

Comment: what difference does it make whether you capture the first or second letter, since they're the same?

Comment: @Barmar because it's followed up with string manipulation to replace whatever got captured with a different substring, and I needed the functionality of "replace all instances of X with Y when preceded/followed by another X". Backreferencing works fine for "followed by X", but not for "preceded by X", and exactly which of the two letters gets matched is important because the output string "XY" is not interchangeable with "YX".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capture groups around both occurrences. Then you can copy one to the replacement to keep it, while replacing the other.

```
string.replace(/([tns])(\1)/g, "X$2"); // replace first with X
string.replace(/([tns])(\1)/g, "$1X"); // replace second with X
```

Comment: Direct string replacement like doesn't do quite what I'm trying to do (which I'm massively simplifying)... but I didn't think to just move the category to the 1st capture group and backreference it in the second - obviating the need to forward-reference in the first place. That will work for my use case so I'll accept it anyway.